# hadoop partitioner getting incorrect reduce count

Tags: hadoop-partitioning

I'm working on partitioner today. Its the basic program in hadoop custom partitioners. Below is my partitioner code snippet.

public class VowelConsPartitioner extends Partitioner {

```
@Override
public int getPartition(Text letterType, IntWritable count, int redCnt) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //System.out.println("reduce cnt in partitioner: "+redCnt);
    if(letterType.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("vowel")){

        //System.out.println("vowel sound: "+1%redCnt);
        return letterType.toString().hasCode()%redCnt;
    }

    if(letterType.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("consonent")){
        //System.out.println("Cons sound: "+2%redCnt);
        return letterType.toString().hasCode()%redCnt;
    }

    else
        return 0;
}
```

}

And I set my reducers in my driver class like this....

job.setNumReduceTasks(3);
job.setPartitionerClass(VowelConsPartitioner.class);

I want to keep more than 1 reducer. But I'm getting the o/p in one reducer only. Moreover if you see the partitioner code, the first sysout(I've commented) was giving me redCnt as 1. I'm not sure how thats happening when I set its count to 3 from my driver class. Could someone help me out on this?

FYI... I'm making jar & running this on HDFS.

Comment: All, its hashCode(). Not hasCode() my bad!!! its a typo

Answer (score 0):

Your Logic is seems to be correct! I guess u need to create a jar file and run it in terminal to get the partitioned result.

Cheers!

Comment: Logic Partitioner https://gist.github.com/krishnakalyan3/6349973  Driver https://gist.github.com/krishnakalyan3/6349965    Reducer   https://gist.github.com/krishnakalyan3/6349961  Mapper  https://gist.github.com/krishnakalyan3/6349950